# Kotlin : Cannot find symbol class Fragment or other android classes

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I have a java fragment with viewPager in it..

```
public class FragmentWithViewPager extends Fragment {

    private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            Fragment fragment = new DeshFalView(); //<-- Problem here
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("index", i);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

    }
}
```

Now I have another fragment which will be populated inside the above fragment and is written in kotlin like this :

```
class DeshFalView : Fragment(), DeshfalContract.View {
    //More code...
}
```

I do not get any lint warning or error but when I try to run the app:

But I get a error :

**Error:(79, 37) error: cannot find symbol class DeshFalView**

in the highlighted line above ..
those two classes are inside same package as shown below [image]

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: Please, show your folder structure.

Comment: I have edited with the folder structure

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Problem :** I made a **stupid mistake** that I **forgot** to `apply kotlin-android` **plugin**

**Solution :** On the top of **app gradle** file paste :

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I had this kind of error even when this:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

was in my app gradle.

The solution is to delete the `app/build` directory. This folder is auto generated so there will be no problems deleting it.

Hope this will help somebody.